# R: ggdotplot issues: how to change colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr, desctools

I have some questions regarding dotplots in R using ggdotplot. There are several issues but I would like to focus on just one for now: I would like to change the fill-color and shape of the "mean_sd" to yellow and a diamond to contrast with the dots. add.params = list(color='"black", fill="yellow", shape = 18, size=1) does not work. I have searched online for examples but can't find any. Here is the minimal example.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dunn.test)
library(conover.test)
library(ggsignif)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
library(rstatix)
library(DescTools)

data("ToothGrowth")
df <- ToothGrowth

ggdotplot(data, x = "dose", y = "len", fill = "supp", add = "mean_sd", 
add.params = list(fill="yellow", shape=1, size=1))
```

The packages listed are used with the rest of my code.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look again at [ask] and the guidance on [mcve]. Try to keep posts to just one question at a time. You can also narrow things down to just the code that's necessary to recreate the issue. It's unclear right now what all the parts of your code do, and how much is necessary for each part of the question

Comment: Hello Camille, thanks for the message. I have edited the question and reduced the code. Is there a way to upload data so I can use my data instead of prepackaged data? Thanks

Comment: There are a lot of suggestions for including data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862), although if the prepackaged data matches the problem, it's fine to use that

Comment: The data I call in the min. ex. work fine to recapitulate the problem. Could you please unclose the post? Thanks